# Unable to edit PDF document from either adobe pro or Preview

Tags: adobe-acrobat, preview

I would like to delete certain pages from a pdf document but my old method, open it in Preview and then click the thumbnail and click the delete button, doesn't seem to work, even though it works in other document.

I think the pdf might be somehow "protected".but the info pages seem to indicate I, as the adminstrator, should be able to access the read&weite priviledge.

I opened it in adobe acrobat pro and still, I am unable to edit the pdf. This time with a more explicit message"..is protected, please enter a Permission Password. If you do not ...."

I downloaded the old document from the internet, so there maybe some kind of copyright protection. But I duplicated the old photo and created a new file.

My question is, what seems to be the problem here and how to solve it.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The rights you see in mobile are related to file permissions, not internal (in pdf) permissions of reader. And this is visible from desktop version. The document is restricted for edit. Contact author/creator and ask for password or not protected document.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple versions/levels of PDF-document passwords.

First there is the so called “open”-password. This is a real encryption, without it you cannot open the document, and the only way to recover it if you forgot it is by cracking the hash of the password using some sort of dictionary or brute force attack.

Second there is the “edit”- or “permissions”-password. With it you can control what a normal user can do with the document, like restricting selecting and copying content or printing pages from the document. If you want to figure out  the password you have to use a similar approach like the one mentioned before, but if you only need the contents of the document you can just easily strip it from these restrictions. The fastest method is to use any chromium based browser like Chrome itself or Microsoft Edge, you only need to open the document and print it again into a new document. This new document is then free if any restrictions. Or you just use one of the many free online tools to remove it.

After removing the password you should be able to edit the document the way you always did, but I would recommend to use a dedicated pdf editor. If you want to use a free and very well working one I can recommend PDF24. Unfortunately it is not available for MacOS at the moment, but you can use all of their tools online on their website.

Comment: Recommending, and even mentioning tools for that, for breaking the file owner's intentions are against the Terms of Usage (IMHO)